# Select multiple drop down menus with different id's in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, select, xpath, css-selectors

I am trying to fill out a form that has a drop down menu for each order number.

```
<select name="order(889673519).box(1).shippingmethod" onclick="" onchange="" 
id="order(889673519).box(1).shippingmethod"><option value="" 
id="order(889673519).box(1).shippingmethod.blank"></option>
```

for each drop down menu the number inside the name css selector will change, so the first one is 889673519
but the second one will be

```
<select name="order(889711159).box(1).shippingmethod" onclick="" onchange="" 
id="order(889711159).box(1).shippingmethod"><option value="" 
id="order(889711159).box(1).shippingmethod.blank"></option>
```

What path do I use to select multiple elements with different names, so I can iterate through them selecting my options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `contains` function:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//select[contains(@name, 'order') and contains(@name, 'shippingmethod')]")
```

Answer (score 0):

To identify the `<select>` nodes using the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector` and *id* attribute:

  ```
  elems = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("select[id^='order'][id*='box'][id$='shippingmethod']")
  ```
- Using `css_selector` and *name* attribute:

  ```
  elems = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("select[name^='order'][name*='box'][name$='shippingmethod']")
  ```
- Using `xpath` and *name* / *id* attribute:

  ```
  elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//select[starts-with(@name, 'order') and contains(@id, 'shippingmethod')]")
  ```